# Overflow hidden does not work on my header image

Tags: html, css

I have this little code in my website, and I want the image to be responsive, so I am using `overflow:hidden`. But this is not working. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```css
.dingdong {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

header img {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="dingdong" src="images/header.jpg" width="100%" height="700px">
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the CSS `width` property to `100%` and `height` to `auto` to make the `img` responsive

```
header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

You can also do this :

```
header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```